# What is the name of the image file used for the white tag backgrounds?

Tags: support, tags

Tags are very difficult for me to see on this site because I use reverse-video colors but the tag background image is hard-wired to be white (so I can't see my light text on it).  On other SE sites I've used AdBlock (in Firefox) to block the background image, but that's not working here, nor is pattern-matching the file name from other sites, nor could I deduce it by inspecting the HTML source for a page here.  Can anybody tell me what file name I need to block -- or, if you've got some other implementation here, how I can turn it off so I can read tag names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually an image, it's a CSS gradient. If you want to adjust the style of the site to match your specific requirements I recommend installing the [Stylebot extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) or [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) with which you can click an element on the page and then change its CSS however you want.

Basically you'll want to find `.post-tag` and then remove or change the `background` rule used by your browser (for Firefox, it'll be the `background: -moz-gradient` rule, etc.). Let me know if you need more help.

(Note that there are more rules being applied to the element so if you remove the gradient it'll fall back to `background-color`, etc.)

**Edit**
OK, so the first thing you do is click the little S in the bottom left of the browser window to open the Stylish context menu. Then select "write new style -> for ux.stackexchange.com". This will pop open a little dialog. Name it whatever you want (like "Fix tag backgrounds") and then in the code field, put the cursor on the line after the one that starts with `@-moz-document` and paste:

```
 .post-tag { background: black !important }
```

Make sure that after this line, there's a `}` to end the contents of the field (which you shouldn't need to add; it should already be there).

Then hit preview to see what happens to the page, and save to save it permanently.

You can play around with different colors if you want; CSS accepts a lot of plain english colors; here's [a chart](http://www.somacon.com/p142.php) (note that if you want to use multiple words, like Pearly Gates, you should surround it in quotes).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  I have Stylish but I don't really know CSS (thus far I've pretty much used it to change font sizes and text colors).  Are you fluent enough to be able to give me an example of the style I could plug in to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Done!

Comment: Thanks very much!